# How to use a variable route with a named router-outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, routerlink

I have a key value pair. The value of the pair is a route. I am using a *named router-outlet*. I cannot find the correct syntax for this. Any help is appreciated.

**.ts:**

```
public myPair: { [key: string]: string } =
{
  'Keyvalue': 'MyRoutHere'
};
```

**.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myPair | keyvalue">
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="accent" [routerLink]="item.value">{{item.key}}</button>
</div>

<router-outlet name="namedRoute"></router-outlet>
```

**module.routes.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'example', component: ExampleMainComponent, children: [
        { path: 'key-value', component: KeyValueComponent, outlet: 'namedRoute' }
    ]
}];
```

*Things I have tried:*

```
'Keyvalue': '[\'/examples\', {outlets: {\'definition\': [\'key-value\']}}]'
'Keyvalue': '(definition:key-value)'
'Keyvalue': '\\key-value'
```

*Errors I get:*

> URL Segment: 'examples/%5B'/examples',%20%7Boutlets:%20%7B'definition':%20%5B'key-value'%5D%7D%7D%5D'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'examples/%5B'/examples',%20%7Boutlets:%20%7B'definition':%20%5B'key-value'%5D%7D%7D%5D'
>
> 'examples/%28definition:key-value%29'
>
> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'examples/key-value'

Answer (score 0):

it failed to read your object, 
  change your ts and html to:

```
  public myPair: { [key: string]: string } =
  {
    Keyvalue: 'MyRoutHere'
  };
```

HTML:

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of myPair | keyvalue">
    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="accent" [routerLink]="item.value">{{item.key}}</button>
    </div>

    <router-outlet name="namedRoute"></router-outlet>
```